# Wide screen 3440x1440 on Fedora

Tags: fedora

I am new to posting stuff on this site, and don't know how to ask a question linked to this almost perfect solution.

I was following this thread
[Unlisted screen resolution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165030/unlisted-screen-resolution?answertab=active#tab-top).

The answer no 1  got me so close to a working screen, but failed after a short while.. ( from a few minutes to a few seconds )

I am running `fedora 5.6.15-300.fc32.x86_64` with the latest updates 2020 06 02
I have a `3440x1440` second screen, I have it stable at `1920x1080`. I went through the steps in answer 1 and got a perfect screen, but then it freezes the system and the screen goes black.

```
cvt 3440 1440 
xrandr
xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-2 3440x1440_60.00
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 3440x1440_60.00
```

Above works fine for a bit...

```
vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-monitor.conf
```

I added this in case it would work on a reboot... no luck

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-2"
    Modeline "3440x1440_60.0" 419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "3440x1440"
EndSection
```

From `dmesg`:

```
264.751057] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  300.325306] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: ERROR 4 [INVALID_ARG] 84 [] chid 0 mthd 0c04 data 008666ac
[  349.728230] CE: hpet4 increased min_delta_ns to 20115 nsec
[  410.515896] CE: hpet3 increased min_delta_ns to 20115 nsec
[  476.495862] hrtimer: interrupt took 22832 ns
```

Anyone had similar problems ?

I might probably crack this, but thought I would see if anything comes back.

Answer (score 1):

I am not informed of your setup and it seems that the output you have posted is related to your network, but the problem is with your X11 server. Have you considered a solution like ARandr? It outputs the config file and maybe you can use the output code and uninstall the program after (if you are hesitant on bloat).

Comment: Thanks for that, I will give arandr a go. from the dmesg the first line i pasted is the end of the boot getting the wireless connected.. then i plugged in the wide monitor and got the last four lines from nouveau.. Im not worried about filling up my system HP mobile workstation 8 cpu 16gb ram 500gb disk

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the arandr gui this has worked fine.
I installed as root using 
yum install arandr

start the gui by typing
arandr

I then clicked on the wide screen monitor, and the resolution I wanted was listed from my previous commands to add this as an option to my DP-2
i.e
cvt 3440 1440 
xrandr       ( to identify the name of my second monitor )
xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-2 3440x1440_60.00

and for some reason the screen is now is stable compared to my previous attempts using the below

xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 3440x1440_60.00